# Can't get Google Cloud Datastore to lock during transaction

Tags: node.js, transactions, locking, google-cloud-datastore

Due to a race condition, I need to lock our datastore during both read & write ops, and according to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#transaction_locks), this is achieved by using transactions. After implementing it as directed, the race condition didn't go away.

After debugging/verifying other parts of the code, I wrote a simple function to test the concurrent behavior (simplified for brevity):

```js
const ds = new Datastore();
const key = ds.key(["some_kind", "some_id"]);

function main() {
  console.log("call 1");
  test(1);

  console.log("call 2");
  test(2);
}

async function test(n) {
  const transaction = ds.transaction();

  await transaction.run();
  console.log("inside transaction ", n);

  const res = await transaction.get(key);
  console.log("got token ", n);

  transaction.save({ key: key, data: res[0] });
  console.log("called save ", n);

  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2 * 1000));
  console.log('slept ', n);

  await transaction.commit();
  console.log("committed transaction ", n);
}
```

Running this, I get:

```bash
call 1
call 2
inside transaction  2
inside transaction  1
got token  2
called save  2
got token  1
called save  1
slept  2
slept  1
committed transaction  2
committed transaction  1
```

I was instead expecting something like this, where the first process that acquired the lock, via the `await transaction.run()` call, would delay other processes requesting the lock:

```bash
call 1
call 2
inside transaction  2
inside transaction  1
got token  2
called save  2
slept  2
committed transaction  2
got token  1
called save  1
slept  1
committed transaction  1
```

Am I misinterpreting the docs regarding how locking works in Datastore? Or is there something wrong with my implementation?

The project uses:

- node @16.14
- @google-cloud/datastore @6.6.2
- Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode

Comment: It looks like key is an incomplete key, this would mean your transactions are working on separate entities and thus won't block on each other.

Comment: Also, given that you don't have any in process locks, each transaction is expected to start, and the only place a lock on the server side could be expressed is in delaying the response to the get RPCs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JimMorrison. About the key, it seems that I made some mistakes while simplifying sample code. It should be fixed now. But in short, I'm using the datastore instance's key function. So, the key should be complete I believe.

Comment: As for the second comment, if I understand what you mean by in process locks correctly, the race condition is happening due to multiple app instances simultaneously reading/writing to that entity. So, in process locks isn't an option I think. As for the delaying action, because I'm not committing the transaction, shouldn't other read/write requests on that entity be delayed until the transaction is committed?

Comment: Yes, and they are.  Notice that you don't get a response back for getting the entity in transaction 2 until you already send the commit for transaction 1.  So at that point we can verify with audit logs that transaction 1 is fully committed before you get any data for the entity in transaction 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as intended.  Transaction 2 runs until it get blocked fetching the shared entity.  Then when the server has committed transaction 1 (somewhere between committing token  1 & committed transaction  1), the response to got token  2 is send and is being processed.

This is to say, transaction 1 is fully committed before transaction 2 gets any data for the entity.

Comment: I added a timeout right before committing the transaction (updated the question post with it), and the second read looks to be getting through before the first transaction's timeout is resolved, meaning that it wasn't yet committed. That leads me to think that the first lock isn't delaying the second read. Am I missing something?

Comment: When I run this code, I get "Error: 10 ABORTED: Aborted due to cross-transaction contention. This occurs when multiple transactions attempt to access the same data, requiring Firestore to abort at least one in order to enforce serializability."

Comment: I seem to be able to reproduce your issue.  If your database is using optimistic concurrency (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/google.firestore.admin.v1#google.firestore.admin.v1.Database.ConcurrencyMode) and the data does not change the transactions are allowed to go through.

Comment: Yes, that could explain, but unfortunately I can't find the option in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/datastore/latest) for the nodejs server client library. Do you know if it in fact exists?

Comment: You'll probably want to use gcloud to check (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/firestore/databases/describe) the database settings.

Comment: It is as you said, looks to be optimistic. Thanks for the help!